# Wordpress Theme: Warning: Illegal string offset 'sidebar'

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

can someone please help me about a couple of PHP errors I am seeing on my Wordpress site?

https://prnt.sc/Gja4uuoyw3-9

These are also the lines in the sidebar.php file.

https://prnt.sc/q6ECaim1sjIn

Any help fixing this issue will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Kind regards,
Erica

Comment: It seems the `$page_meta` is not an `array` as expected, but rather a `string`. How could that have happened?

Comment: Hello and thank you for taking the time to get back to me.

To be honest I don't know. That is how the theme came.

Do you know how I can change or fix this please as I don't know anything about PHP sorry?

Thank you very much.

Kind regards,
Erica

Comment: Don't post images of text please

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I thought it was easier but I can see now how it isn't.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `$page_meta` is not an array as expected, but rather a string. My guess is that the theme expects those variable names as meta variables for that page.
It also has something to do with the sidebar, used or not.

Got it. I searched google looking for theme name by `smt_getOption` then I saw this:

```php
/* aproximadamente es en a linea 26 */

/*
cod original:

$page_meta[ 'sidebar' ] = 'smt_default_sidebar';
$page_meta[ 'sidebar_position' ] = smt_getOption( 'layout', 'pagelayout' );*/

/* la correcion: */

$page_meta = array('sidebar'=>'smt_default_sidebar','sidebar_position'=>smt_getOption( 'layout', 'pagelayout' ));
```

Comment: WOW thank you so very much and I will give it a shot later on and get back to you. I really appreciate you helping me with this.

Can I buy you a beer or coffee?

If so please let me know.

Thank you so very much once again!

Comment: Once again thank you so very much and I implemented your fix and that error is now gone.

One more thing though if you can please help me again? I just had a quick look in the error log file and now I am seeing this error:

Comment: [03-Aug-2022 23:18:01 UTC] PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home13/mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/hotsteel/footer.php on line 10 [03-Aug-2022 23:18:01 UTC] PHP Warning: Division by zero in /home13/mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/hotsteel/footer.php on line 23

Comment: Do you know how this can be fixed as well?

Thanks.

Comment: The division by zero is because the `count` on a non-array. What's on lines 1-10?

Comment: Line 10 has: $cnt = count( $total_widgets['smt_footer_sidebar'] );

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how this formatting works as everything is bunched together without a paragrahs. So here is a screenshot of that area: 

https://prnt.sc/4V5DC_TcukEQ

Comment: Line 23 has: footer .widget { width: <?php echo (102-2*$cnt)/$cnt; ?>%; }

Comment: Once again so very sorry for the screenshot. https://prnt.sc/_FAHT6jidgjm

Comment: Thank you so very much for any additional help.

Comment: It's probably something with the footer widgets. Maybe you don't have them at the moment. If it works without I wouldn't worry. Just maybe add an `if` before dividing by `$cnt`. You can tell it's for deciding the width of each widget.